# How do I get an item from an array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array inside of an array. How do i get the item from the array which is stored in another array?

EX

```
array = new array(),
array2 = new array();
array2[0] = "I need this" 
array[0] = array2;
//How do i get the item in the second array
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as this:

```
array[0][0];
```

Although your code won't parse correctly, you've used `array` as both a var name and a constructor name.  The correct constructor is `Array`, but I would create it with `array = []` or for less ambiguity, don't use `array` as a variable name at all.

Comment: Sorry, i know that but i was only using this as a quick example

Comment: @rainbowfox No worries -- it helps to be correct even in quick examples, since there are so many different ways things can go wrong.  Just trying to get you the answer you need!

Answer (score 0):

```
array = new array(),
array2 = new array();

for (var i in array)
    for (var j in array[i])
        // array[i][j] will give you the required element.
        document.write(array[i][j];
```